# How can I insert into PostgreSQL using Perl, DBI and placeholders?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbi

I am trying to insert a row into a pSQL table, specifying both keys and values as placeholders:

```
my @keys = keys %db_entr;                                                            
my @vals = values %db_entr;

my @items = (@keys, @values);

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:Pg:dbname=testdb;host=localhost", "username", 'password', {'RaiseError' => 1});                                                                   
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO grid ( ?, ?, ? ) values ( ?, ?, ? )");
my $rows = $sth->execute(@items);                                                    
print "$rows effected\n";
```

However, whatever I do, this gives me an error:

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO grid ( $1, $2, ...
                           ^ at ./file.pl line 262, <STDIN> line 11.
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: your code example doesn't make sense, you aren't showing where `@items` is created

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use placeholders for column names in the `prepare` call. The best you can do is to either interpolate the variable names into the SQL string or use `sprintf` to do the equivalent.

This is an example, but you may need to do something different. Note that it modifies the `@items` array, and you need to call `prepare` again each time the contents of `@items` may have changed.

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare(
    sprintf "INSERT INTO grid ( %s, %s, %s ) values ( ?, ?, ? )",
    splice @items, 0, 3
);
my $rows = $sth->execute(@items);
print "$rows affected\n";
```

Comment: A word of warning (belated as it may be): doing this with user-provided column names defeats the purpose of using prepared statements in the first place, since it will make you vulnerable to SQL injection again.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot use placeholders for column names like this:

```
INSERT INTO grid (?, ?, ?) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

You must specify column names explicitly and can use placeholders for values only:

```
INSERT INTO grid (x, y, z) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```